# Delphi, connecting Postgres with FireDAC through SSH

Tags: delphi, ssh, firedac

I am looking for a free solution to create an SSH tunnel for a connection to Postgres.

I tried to use this example (https://blogs.embarcadero.com/connecting-databases-with-firedac-through-ssh)
,but I get an error all the time.

[image]

I can't find the reason.
I use Delphi 11, Windows 32bit app

Comment: From what I can make out from the error the client is trying to authenticate the host, which normally means it's trying to validate the certificate.  Is the certificate valid?  Is the Certificate Authority known?  You will need to get the host trusted to go further...

Comment: I do not use a certificate. I use login and password for authentication. As in the example ...   
ssh -L 5000:localhost:5432 login@host -p 5890

Comment: What's visible of the error message shows that it's trying to authenticate the host - so you should have a certificate.  That's typically how SSH works, both the server and the user have certificates.

Comment: The example I pasted also performs authentication based on login and password. SSH authentication keys are not always used

Comment: Hi @Olaf - the error message clearly shows that it's trying to authenticate the host.  If you don't get past that you won't perform client validation because the client won't present.  If the client authentication is accepted you may then have to login to the application on the other side of the ssh tunnel.

Comment: @RobLambden look at:  https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/ssh-tunneling-pgadmin-4
There are two types of authorization:

a) By password 

b) with keys

Comment: Hi @Olaf - I understand that - I have been using SSH for at least 20 years.  I believe you are thinking about user authentication.  The error message you have shown indicates that client is not accepting the hosts' certificate so it won't present credentials.  This is by design to protect against a man in the middle attack or an unrecgnised host.  If the host presents a certificate which the client rejects it will never present any authentication of its own.